# Настройка и отображение шрифта в css (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, шрифты

у меня настроен шрифт в React, когда я захожу на страницу я вижу кастомный шрифт, а другие пользователи, заходящие на эту же страницу, видят default шрифт, то есть они не видят мой кастомный шрифт, в директории вместе с моим css лежит папка fonts, где лежат эти шрифты

````
    --main-font-family: 'Cushy';
    --secondary-font-family: 'Maki-Sans';
    --font-family: 'Peace Sans';
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cushy';
    src: url('./fonts/Cushy.otf') format('otf'),
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Maki-Sans';
    src: url('../css/fonts/MakiSans.otf') format('otf'),
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Peace Sans';
    src: url('../css/fonts/PeaceSans.otf') format('otf'),
}

@keyframes animation {
    100% {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}```
````

Comment: А браузеры одни и те же используете? На сколько я помню, разные браузеры хотят шрифты в разных форматах. [Более подробно про шрифты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts)

Comment: Да, по разному пробовали

Comment: У кого не отображается шрифт, пусть откроет панель разработчика и посмотрит вкладку сеть(network). Там наверняка будет ошибка 404 или какая другая. Может чего будет в консоли полезного.